# adding connecting lines to scatter plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a function to customize marker and color conditionally for each data point.

```
def mscatter(x,y,ax=None, m=None, **kw):
   import matplotlib.markers as mmarkers
   if not ax: ax=plt.gca()
   sc = ax.scatter(x,y,**kw)
   if (m is not None) and (len(m)==len(x)):
     paths = []
     for marker in m:
        if isinstance(marker, mmarkers.MarkerStyle):
            marker_obj = marker
        else:
            marker_obj = mmarkers.MarkerStyle(marker)
        path = marker_obj.get_path().transformed(
                    marker_obj.get_transform())
        paths.append(path)
    sc.set_paths(paths)
  return sc
```

Then I have some data for x, y, and corresponding color and markers for x, y.

```
col = np.where(this_data['ifAgentCorrect'],"g","r")
mrkr = np.where(this_data['ifCorrectDecisions'],"o","x")
x = range(len(this_data['ifCorrectDecisions']))
y = this_data['cumSum']

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8))
scatter = mscatter(x, y, c=col, m=mrkr)
plt.show()
```

All I need to do is to connect the scatter point with lines. Which is usually done using markers like 'o-', 'x-'. But `matplotlib.markers` doesn't have 'o-' or 'x-' in its list of markers. so I get the error `ValueError: Unrecognized marker style o-`. Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this? Thank you.

Comment: The point of scatter plot is to not have lines. You could use `plt.plot` instead (or in addition to).

Comment: And when you use `plt.plot`, you will see, that `x-` or `o-` are actually valid options